# How to sum multi record base on on column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

```
    codea       MainType    value
------------------------------------
    10          a           20765
    11          NULL        414
    11          b           12
    12          c           247809
    20          NULL        700
    20          d           50
```

How can I group by on `codea` and sum values based on `maintype` and main type null removed, and get result like this table:

```
codea       MainType    value
-------------------------------
10          a            20765
11          b              426
12          c           247809
20          d              750
```

Thanks for reading my question

Comment: plus `11          f          12` ,  then..?

Comment: @Serg: this sounds like a 'you should normalize your database ….' remark ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your sample data I see that you can get rid of nulls with `max(maintype)`:

```
select
  codea,
  max(maintype) maintype,
  sum(value) value
from tablename
group by codea
```

Comment: In this answer you also could have used `min(maintype)` (or any other aggregate function which is allowed to work with strings) because NULL values are ignored in aggregate functions.

Comment: *... you also could have used...* sure, but I have to use only one.

Comment: yes, but if the record Serg posted is added to the database, this solution produces results that might be confusing to someone... (because `codea=11` would have a `maintype` with value 'f' )

Comment: This is why I start my answer: *by the sample data...*. If the requirement is different, then it's the OP's responsibility to clarify or handle.